# Rendering error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Apologies for the generic title but I'm not sure how best to explain this one.

Visual Studio is rendering badly in a number of locations, notably the Quick Watch window, Unit Test Sessions window and the Unit Test context menu, see screenshot at the below url. It has been this way since I installed Visual Studio 2012, the OS at the time was Windows 7 and I upgraded to Windows 8 recently so it is not a Windows 8-specific issue.

[image]

This is Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 Pro. The machine is a Core i5 with 12GB of Ram running at 1% CPU and 3Gb of Ram used so it's definitely not a problem with lack of power, which is the only time I have ever seen any rendering faults like this.

I have tried a repair install and also uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio but it has made no difference.

This issue occurs solely in Visual Studio 2012, not in any other applications on the computer nor on VS2010 when I had that installed.

Some frantic googling has revealed nothing and I am out of ideas.

**Solution**

Downloaded some old Vista/Windows 7 drivers from [here](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2007/ATI_Catalyst_11.6_Software_Suite_Vista7_64-bit.html) which solved my problem.

Comment: Crappy video drivers maybe?

Comment: Drivers are on the latest available version from June. If it were video drivers I would expect it to be more widespread than just these 3 specific areas.

Comment: If it were me, I'd try switching to some super generic standard VGA drivers or something, even if you have to switch to 800x600 resolution.  Just to eliminate the possibility.

Comment: I stand corrected. I reverted to the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter, which dropped me down to 800x600 and the rendering faults went away. Have reverted to the driver I was using before and they are back. Wouldn't of expected dodgy drivers to manifest in such a specific way...

Comment: Well at least you know the culprit.  The makers of your video card might have a support channel you can go through, or if your video card isn't all that great to begin with, maybe time to head over to NewEgg for a late Christmas present.

Comment: Its a Radeon HD 4800 which is only a few years old. ATI released some new drivers yesterday which I am now downloading so hopefully that will sort things. If you repost your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the answer as you have helped me find the culprit.

Comment: I have the same problem with my Radeon 6970 in my iMac 27". Just about to give the latest driver a shot. I'll report back.

Comment: Tested and failed: No difference with 13.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely culprit is the video drivers.  I'd confirm by switching to the *Basic VGA Display* driver to rule out video driver issues.

If this fixes the issue, I'd look for different video drivers or report the problem to the card manufacturer.

Comment: Quick update: Latest drivers didn't work, it's off to the ATI forums I go!